# Error when attempting to insert "standard skipping condition" with custom agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am trying configure a custom agenda view with multiple blocks.

For one of the blocks, I want to skip items that have are scheduled or have a deadline in order to find "unscheduled" items (this was an example from here https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Agenda-Views.html).

I am using the following view in the Customize agenda, to add these "local settings" for this custom agenda block. When I click "INS[ert]" under "Conditions for skipping", I get the following error:

`Wrong type argument: listp or regexp`

When choosing a value after clicking "INS[ert]", I get the error:

`Marker does not point anywhere`

[image]

Debug output here: https://pastebin.com/TfC0wN9c

Comment: `org-agenda-custom-commands` is a complicated variable and I fear that the Customize interface to it is making things worse. Are you interested in an answer on how to get the agenda to behave the way you want? If so, there is hope: somebody (maybe me except for the lack of time) might provide a Lisp snippet that you can add to your init file and make an end-run around the Customize mess. OTOH, if you want an answer on why Customize barfs, then somebody (else) might provide an answer, but you will probably need to add more details so that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your last sentence: if you *are* interested in why Customize barfs, then that debugging output is essential - do add it to your question, even if only as a link to some pastebin site.

Comment: Thanks @NickD — added pastebin link to show the output. It seems I can futz with the customize output code in my init file to get these variables added, but things don't get reflected in the customize UI. Ultimately I just want to get this working, which just means being able to enable the skip option!

Comment: Ah, yes - that is going to take a little while to take in, let alone digest :-)

Comment: @NickD Yes...I couldn't believe how big the output was! Thanks for taking a look, appreciate your responses :)